# How many 7-digit phone numbers are possible, assuming that the first digit can’t be a 0 or a 1

Tags: combinatorics

I use the multiplication rule. 
For the first digit I have 8 choices. For the last 6 digits I have 10 choices for each. So answer is $8 \cdot 10 ^6$.

Is there any other way to solve this problems. I usually gain a lot of insight from solving the problems in different ways. Please write which theorems etc. you have used.

Answer (score 7):

What you have said is basically correct, but perhaps a more "formal" way (which is where the multiplication rule comes from) is to construct the *set* of all possibilities, and find its cardinality.

Let $A = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, and $B = A \smallsetminus \{0,1\}$. Then the set of all possible phone numbers is $B \times A^6$, and therefore the number of possible phone numbers is
$$|B\times A^6| = |B||A^6|=|B||A|^6 = 8\cdot10^6.$$

Answer (score 7):

Another way to look at it is to take the highest possible $7$-digit number and subtract the lowest possible: $9,999,999-2,000,000+1=8,000,000$ (we need to add $1$ as we count $2000000$ as a valid number)

Comment: How does this work. I do not understand. But it works :-)

Comment: True, but this only happens to work because all of the valid numbers are adjacent.

Comment: @Xenusi: this is just counting all whole numbers between two given numbers.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Why numbering should start at zero, Dijkstra 1982](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html)

Answer (score 1):

number of 7 digit numbers ( including leading 0):  10,000,000

number of 7 digit numbers including lead 0 or 1 :  - 2,000,000

number of 7 digit numbers not lead by 0 or 1 :          8,000,000

This more just taking a complement of a set. ( so an interior form of inclusion-exclusion)

You could realize all 7 have at least 8, get $8^7$ then realize each of 6 have 2 more with the seventh having $8=2^3$, for $2^9$ and have fun adding up all $64=2^6$ combinations all together. More a property of a powerset which relates to combinations, as the total number of combinations of all sizes, is the number of distinguishable states which in includes all subsets, (Also tedious)

Comment: That's immediately what I thought when reading the title. Simple answer to a simple question. This should be the accepted answer as anything more complicated is will be of no benefit to this particular question.